# Query multiple date ranges in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to query for multiple date ranges in mongoose. I still tried:

```
Model.find({
  my_date: [
    // range 1
    {
      "$gte": new Date(),
      "$lt": new Date()
    },
    {
      "$gte": new Date(),
      "$lt": new Date()
    },
    // ...
  ]
});
```

The problem is that it throws an error: "Cast to date failed for value [object Object]".

Therefore I expect that mongoose interprets the array as just one input element and not a list of them. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Thank you :-)

Best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were just missing an `$or` clause:

```
Model.find({
  $or: [
    { // range 1
      my_date: { '$gte': new Date(), '$lt': new Date() }
    },
    { // range 2
      my_date: { '$gte': new Date(), '$lt': new Date() }
    }
  ]
}, callback);
```

Comment: So simple, works and solved my problem. Thank you for your great and fast help! :-)